# What constitutes a control (vs printable) character in Boost's regular expression 'cntrl' character class?

Tags: regex, boost, notepad++

I am making notes in notepad++ on notepad++'s regular expressions, which supposedly uses the same syntax as regular expressions do in Perl, which supposedly uses the [Boost library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) and its character classes [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/character_classes/std_char_classes.html).  However, the previous page leaves a lot to be desired, as what constitutes a control, graphical, and printable character are undefined.  After doing a lot of research I found that other languages define printable characters as non-control characters, and [this source](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) claims that anything that adheres to the POSIX standard does the same.  However, using the expression \p{cntrl} I found Notepad++'s Find and Replace feature will match many control characters to printable characters, including carriage returns, line feeds, and even form feeds.  I don't have time to test \p{cntrl} against every character in Unicode, so can someone just please give me Notepad's definition?

Comment: What about `\p{Cc}`? That should map to the Unicode 'Control' class which is well-defined.

Comment: I guess you want `[[:cntrl:]]+` (control) and `[^[:cntrl:]]+` (printable)

Comment: CRs, LFs and FFs do not place ink onto paper when they are printed, they control the movement of the print head. Hence they are control characters.

Comment: \p{Cc} isn't valid.
P.S. I have Notepad++ v7.8.4 (32 bit)